# SEO alternative for website with iframe

Tags: seo, iframe

We have a website with its content loading in iframe except header and footer.
Since SEO bot does not consider iframe, it affect seo rankings.

what are the alternate ways to put the shorter version of iframe content in parent page with its visibility hidden so that crawlers can read it

it seems display:none is not allowed

can we use  with heading tags for this (h1...h6)

or please let us know the correct approach to deal with this
NOTE: we can not remove iframe, we just need way to put some seo friendly information in dom on top of iframe so that crawler can catch it and its also not visible to user

Answer (score 3):

Google considers the content of an iframe as part of the main page's content. I last updated my article on it in January 2022.

I'm not sure how other search engines deal with iframes.